# Why set max-age=0 if no-store is already set?

Tags: http, header

A result of a recent pentest suggested that the HTTP Cache-Control Header `max-age=0` should be set when `no-store` is set.

As I understand cache control, `no-store` is the strictest we can set; the page should not even land in cache, let alone need to be revalidated. So why would setting `max-age=0`, i.e. that the content is stale on arrival, help, in particular in a security context such as login?

The only thing that occurs to me is that some browsers may not support the `no-store` header. If we do not support such browsers, there would not be a need to add extra cache control headers, right?

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information to comment on the validity of the recommendation.

TL;DR The addition of `max-age=0` to the Cache-Control header could provide some additional security by stating the response is stale and not to use any cached responses.

The `no-store` Cache-Control is to prevent the inadvertent release or retention of sensitive information.  At the bottom of the definition it includes this:

> The purpose of this directive is to meet the stated requirements
> of certain users and service authors who are concerned about
> accidental releases of information via unanticipated accesses to
> cache data structures. While the use of this directive might
> improve privacy in some cases, we caution that it is NOT in any
> way a reliable or sufficient mechanism for ensuring privacy. In
> particular, malicious or compromised caches might not recognize or
> obey this directive, and communications networks might be
> vulnerable to eavesdropping.

So by adding the `max-age=0` should force a reload of caches since the age would be stale and a refresh would occur.

In addition, OWASP mentions but doesn't elaborate on:

> These [no-cache and no-store] directives are generally robust, although additional flags may be necessary for the Cache-Control header in order to better prevent persistently linked files on the file system. These include:
> Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=0, s-maxage=0

And finally, and this may not apply to your situation:

> The no-store directive prevents a response from being stored, but does not delete any already-stored response for the same URL.
> In other words, if there is an old response already stored for a particular URL, returning no-store will not prevent the old response from being reused.

NOTE: Several of the references caution against the "kitchen-sink" approach to Cache-Control.  Tread carefully, your mileage may vary.

**References**
[RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616)
[OWASP Testing for Browser Cache Weaknesses](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/04-Authentication_Testing/06-Testing_for_Browser_Cache_Weaknesses)
[Web HTTP Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
[Why both no-cache and no-store..in HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866822/why-both-no-cache-and-no-store-should-be-used-in-http-response)

Comment: Thanks. What potentially confuses me is the order of the requests/use of the cache. Does the client make a new request before looking in the cache (and get new headers) or does it also cache the headers and use them to determine whether to use the cached content? Getting the updated headers would be the only way it could receive a new `max-age=0` directive. If it decides whether to use the cache based on the _cached_ headers, retroactively setting `max-age=0` would make no difference.

Comment: Retroactively, there is little you can do but that doesn't mean you shouldn't take additional steps for future use.  The Web HTTP Caching link has a section about deleting stored responses, spoiler alert, there's not much you can do from the server side.  Big picture, 99.99999% of all caches will not be tampered with so having `no-store` wouldn't be an issue.  Adding the `max-age=0` would help for that one in a million ignoring that directive.

Comment: So the tl;dr is that it's for caches and/or browsers that don't support `no-store`? Then I should be following the kitchen sink approach and at least also include `must-revalidate`?

Comment: That depends on what browsers and browser versions you support and what version of http you support.  MS implements Cache-Control differently than Firefox or Chrome.  I would test the Cache-Control on all the browsers my application supports to determine what settings are best.  I've added another reference to an SO post you may find helpful

Comment: So I guess my last question is, if I have `max-age=0, must-revalidate` in addition to `no-store` because a cache may not support `no-store` or `no-cache`, why do I need `no-cache` as well...? Surely that is covered with `max-age=0` and `must-revalidate`, which are both "more reliable"?